# find single data attribute value from multiple values JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to find a single data- value. Below is my sample code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-aclass="Question1" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion1 Attention" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion2 Physical" />
```

```js
$(':text[data-aclass^=Que]').on("change", function() {
  var currentQuestion = "",
    inQuestion = "";
  currentQuestion = $(this).data("aclass");
  var inQ = "in" + currentQuestion;
  inQuestion = $("[data-aclass='" + inQ + "']");
});
```

Here, `$("[data-aclass='" + inQ + "']")` gives me `0` length and if I remove `Attention` from the `data` attribute it gives me the result I want.
What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your selector is `[data-aclass='inQuestion1']`, which requires an *exact* match on the value, yet the element(s) you're looking for have other values in the attribute as well as `inQuestionN`. As such you need to use the 'attribute begins with' selector there too:

```js
$(':text[data-aclass^=Que]').on('change', function() {
  var currentQuestion = '', inQuestion = '';
    
  currentQuestion = $(this).data('aclass');
  var inQ = 'in' + currentQuestion;
  inQuestion = $('[data-aclass^="' + inQ + '"]'); // note ^ here
  
  console.log(inQuestion.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-aclass="Question1" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion1 Attention" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion2 Physical" />
```

*Edit:*

Given your comments below regarding greedy matches with `inQuestion10` etc, then a workaround would be to use `filter()` instead. Then you can split the data attribute to an array and determine if the exact value is contained within it:

```js
$(':text[data-aclass^=Que]').on('change', function() {
  var currentQuestion = $(this).data('aclass');
  var inQ = 'in' + currentQuestion;
  
  var $inQuestion = $('[data-aclass]').filter(function() {
    var values = $(this).data('aclass').split(' ');
    return values.indexOf(inQ) != -1;
  });
  
  console.log($inQuestion.data('aclass'));
  console.log($inQuestion.length);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-aclass="Question1" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion1 Attention" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion2 Physical" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion10 Physical" />
<input type="text" data-aclass="inQuestion111 Physical" />
```

Comment: Hi @Rory, starts with is perfectly fine in this case but what if there are 20 elements? If there is "Question1" then I want only "inQuestion1" and not all elements that have "inQuestion11,12,13...".Thank you.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest separating your `data` attrbutes, eg `data-aclass="inQuestion1" data-type="Attention"`. Then you can use the attribute equals selector as you did originally.

Comment: I would love to if I could. Let me tell you the exact scenario. In the application I am working on, there is a Form Builder control in which one can 
drag and drop a textbox and set its properties. In "Advance class" property of textbox if I write "inQuestion1 Attention", the value gets set in it's "data-aclass" attribute. So as you suggested, to seperate the data attr it is not possible in my case.
Can you please tell me a work around?

Comment: No problem, glad to help